# qt + opengl gluLookAt issue

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

i'm writing simple 2d game and i have to do some stuff in qt. Game runs good , it was written in vs 2015 , now i moved it into qt creator.

There is opengl widget to display graphic. I've added things in .pro file and i can use opengl function except gluLookAt(used in timer function cscenaqt) , i get error :

```
    cscenaqt.obj:-1: błąd: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol gluLookAt referenced in function "protected: virtual void __cdecl cScenaQt::timerEvent(class QTimerEvent *)" (?timerEvent@cScenaQt@@MEAAXPEAVQTimerEvent@@@Z)
```

Here is opengl widget file

```
#ifndef CSCENAQT_H
#define CSCENAQT_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QGLWidget>

class cScenaQt : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT        // must include this if you use Qt signals/slots

public:
    cScenaQt(QWidget *parent);

protected:

    void initializeGL();

    void resizeGL(int w, int h);

    void paintGL();
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * event);
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* e);

    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event);
private:
    float m_x,m_y;
    int m_timer_id;
};

#endif // CSCENAQT_H
```

Here is .pro file

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2016-05-25T04:49:19
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui opengl

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = openglqt
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    cscenaqt.cpp \
    bielan_przeszkoda_1.cpp \
    boss.cpp \
    czlowiek.cpp \
    figura.cpp \
    figury.cpp \
    fizyka.cpp \
    funckje.cpp \
    gnom.cpp \
    gracz.cpp \
    pawlak_slupki.cpp \
    pawlak_wieze.cpp \
    pawlak_winda.cpp \
    przeszkoda.cpp \
    wrobel_dzialo.cpp \
    wrobel_gate.cpp \
    wrobel_kolec.cpp \
    wrobel_most.cpp \
    wrobel_przepasc.cpp \
    wrobel_przeszkoda_1.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    cscenaqt.h \
    bielan_przeszkoda_1.h \
    boss.h \
    czlowiek.h \
    figura.h \
    figury.h \
    fizyka.h \
    funckje.h \
    gnom.h \
    gracz.h \
    pawlak_slupki.h \
    pawlak_wieze.h \
    pawlak_winda.h \
    przeszkoda.h \
    wrobel_dzialo.h \
    wrobel_gate.h \
    wrobel_kolec.h \
    wrobel_most.h \
    wrobel_przepasc.h \
    wrobel_przeszkoda_1.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
LIBS += opengl32.lib
```

How can i fix this issue and is there some way to allow user to use more than one key in qt(i know it was possible in opengl with glkeyupfun and keydown , smth like this)?

Comment: then i get :-1: błąd: LNK1104: cannot open file 'GLU.lib',

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too sure about Windows, but according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368663(v=vs.85).aspx it's called `Glu32.lib`, hence add `LIBS += -lGlu32`. This has very little to do with Qt, you just need to link the libraries you want to use.

Comment: LIBS += -lGlu32 worked, there are no errors but i doesnt change camers position , im confused